# Compile code only

Tags: iphone

How can I execute only code? I have a huge bundle (about 1000 images) and it takes a lot of time to copy all the photos with every build and run. Is there any way "deselect"? Regards.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "deselect" images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple targets for the same app. Duplicate your current target, select most of your images in the project navigator, and then uncheck the new target in the Target Membership pane in the file inspector. Now, you can build the new target and test your app with only a few of your images.

Comment: And do you know how can I check the copy of target as main target. I work with Xcode 4 and there's no checkbox like in previous version of  Xcode. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'main target'. You just build the target that you're interested in -- one isn't more 'main' than another.

Answer (score 0):

create a separate target for your compilation phase -- for example, a static library